# Solve issue inversing a large matrix with complex numbers

Tags: r, complex-numbers, matrix-inverse

I have a randomly generated matrix with complex components that I need to inverse using R. Ideally this matrix will be around 200x200.

Oddly, it works when the matrix is small (up to dim of 6x6) but quickly fails as I increase the dimension, even though the function solve doesn't produce an error message:

```
set.seed(123)
tj<-sample(seq(from=0, to=1, by=0.001), 50)
matdim<-4 # this is the element that i'm progressively increasing
M.mat<-matrix(data=NA, nrow=matdim, ncol=matdim)
for(i in 1:matdim){
  for(j in 1:matdim){
    M.mat[i,j]<-exp(complex(real=0, imaginary=pi*tj[j]*(2*i-51)/50)) 
  }
} 
round(M.mat%*%solve(M.mat),3)[1:min(10, matdim),1:min(10, matdim)] 
# should be diag(1)
round(sum(M.mat%*%solve(M.mat)),3) # should be equal to mat.dim
```

It's fine up to about mat.dim=6 or 7, then it starts getting progressively worse.

I checked if the issue came from the fact I'm using exponentials of complex numbers but this other example works without any issue:

```
mat.dim<-1000
C.mat<-matrix(data=exp(complex(real=0, imaginary=rnorm(mat.dim*mat.dim, sd=1000))), 
              nrow=mat.dim, ncol=mat.dim)
C.mat[1:min(10,mat.dim),1:min(10, mat.dim)]
round(C.mat%*%solve(C.mat),3)[1:min(10,mat.dim),1:min(10, mat.dim)] # is diag(1)
round(sum(C.mat%*%solve(C.mat)),3) # equals mat.dim
```

Would anyone have any idea why the inversion fails in the first example?

Comment: Can you check my edit?

Comment: how is your edit helpful?

Comment: You only defined `mat.dim` in your second code block, so it was giving errors. (Run the code a clean session.)